# Error as a result of purging unity8-lxc

Tags: 15.10, lxc

```
user@user-K53SD:~$ sudo apt-get purge unity8-lxc
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done

The following packages will be REMOVED:
 unity8-lxc*
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 to remove and 3 not upgraded.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
(Reading database ... 216814 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing unity8-lxc (1.0.5-0~79~201510271721~ubuntu15.10.1) ...
Purging configuration files for unity8-lxc (1.0.5-0~79~201510271721~ubuntu15.10.1) ...
lxc-destroy: lxccontainer.c: container_destroy: 2168 Error destroying rootfs for unity8-lxc
Destroying unity8-lxc failed
dpkg: error processing package unity8-lxc (--purge):
subprocess installed post-removal script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 unity8-lxc
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: What is your current desktop environment? Please, post the outputs of - `echo $DESKTOP_SESSION` and `echo $XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP`

Comment: echo $DESKTOP_SESSION - ubuntu. Desktop environment - Unity

Comment: And the other???

Comment: And also this -  `unity --version`

Comment: version - unity 7.3.2

Comment: Try this `sudo apt-get autoremove unity8-lxc`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct command to uninstall `unity8-lxc` is:

```
sudo apt-get autoremove unity8-lxc
```